# How do you know when an interface is out of bandwidth?

Tags: networking, router, bandwidth, openwrt, network-interface

I'm uncertain about this, probably because my background isn't in networking, but in programming instead;  I know how to setup a basic LAN and an OpenWRT router, but I don't really understand how to monitor when I'm running out of bandwidth; or how much bandwidth has been used for a month etc...

What I do know is that each interface / port on a router has a speed specification like 10/100/1000 10/100/1000 Mbps (Megabits per second).

Now my assumption is that when something close to this speed is reached, then you are running out of bandwidth for an interface, provided of course that the  connection on the other end is capable of that speed, and that the media it is flowing over supports that much bandwidth.

[image: Image of Grafana monitoring bandwidth on an OpenWRT router]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for SNMP. 
(Simple network management protocol)
It will allow you to monitor bandwidth in/out on each port that is setup to use it.

The router needs to be configured for SNMP.
And additionally you need software running on a computer to monitor it. I personally use solarwinds tools. But "free SNMP" on your favorite search engine should yield plenty of results.

https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/snmp.server

Comment: I was going to try and use Grafana to monitor it...mainly because I can set alerts...the graph in the question above is from my current setup and influx and graphana already receive that information (at least I think it does) ... Does it look like it's monitoring the wrong thing?

Comment: These graphs work well when you are experiencing issues. But routers do not normally have enough memory to save this data long term. You will know when you maxing out bandwidth, it will be the max Mbps of the two interfaces connected to it. I.e if you have a 100Mbps link you will see a steady line in your graph at 100Mbps when it's maxing out. BTW, it doesn't look to me like your router is reading bps correctly, as your bridge interface is in the negative. "-572"

Comment: Run a speed test, somewhere like speakeasy.net and watch this graph while it's downloading. write down your max from the router and compare your speeds to the graph.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear that I'm sending the data to a separate machine which runs InfluxDB and it's viewed in Grafana...the router doesn't store the data, it sends it via collectd.

Comment: Whatever you are using doesn't seem to be collecting data properly. Use a standardized protocol.

Comment: Okay I'll give SNMP a try, it looks like there's a way to use that with influxdb: https://github.com/paulstuart/influxsnmp, and another way to do it with telegraf: https://www.dev-eth0.de/blog/2016/12/06/grafana_snmp.html like you said.